# How do you write Gulp tasks in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm, gulp

How do you write Gulp tasks in TypeScript?

I've seen projects like [this](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) where they write gulp tasks in TypeScript so I know it is possible, but I'm having a hard time finding out how they set this up.

Comment: I usually just use vanilla javascript for my gulp scripts because typically once written they don't change too often and so transpiling (to me) doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I you really want to do it however there is nothing special about a gulp file compared to any other javascript file. As Justin mentioned in his answer, just get the plugin for it and check the examples. It is really straightforward.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I have used that library before it is really easy to use. You could write your gulpfile.js through a gulpfile.ts but you would need to run the compiler before running gulp. In the repo I linked to, they don't require you to compile the gulpfile.ts. You just run gulp and it runs. It has to be compiled at some point but I even did a project search and they never compile the gulpfile.ts to gulpfile.js and somehow Gulp is fine with this I don't get it.

Comment: One way is to tell typescript to watch files and compile automatically. This is not happening here from what I can see. What I think IS happening is that if you open the tsconfig.json file you will see that the 'exclude' option is specified. According to the docs, 'If the "exclude" property is specified, the compiler includes all TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except for those files or folders that are excluded.'.

Comment: Another way is via typescript script in browser. If you look at the system.js.conf at this example you can see how the angular team is doing it. http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 10):

Ok, after a bit a digging and dicing this project up I found it.

To run gulpfile.ts without compiling the file you can use the '[ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)' package. This package lets you run TypeScript directly in node and in this case you can use it to run gulp which will compile and run TypeScript on the fly while running your gulp tasks.

I didn't mean to answer my own question but it you find it you might as well share it.